# Python git determine if project has SSH or PWD authentication

Tags: python, git, authentication

I have a GUI application that uses the pythongit library to perform updates. When a user is authenticating with a SSH key to the repository the updates works smoothly, but when a username/password authentication is used, then a prompt will appear on the terminal where the application was started (leaving the user with the GUI interface open thinking it's frozen).

Is there a way to determine if the repo is using SSH or password authentication and then possibly manually prompt for a username/password first and passing it to the `fetch` call?

Here is the basic functionality:

```
def repo_pull(self, git_path):
    try:
        repo = Repo(git_path)
    except InvalidGitRepositoryError as igre:
        raise ValueError('Get the project as a Git repository (no archives)')

    commits_ahead = repo.iter_commits('origin/master..master')

    if sum(1 for c in commits_ahead) > 0:
        raise ValueError("Can't pull from git; local repository has unpushed commits!")

    origin = repo.remote()
    try:
        origin.fetch()
    except GitCommandError as gce:
        ,,,
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to see if the remote is accessed with HTTPS or SSH

```
def _determine_authentication(self, repo):
    config_reader = repo.config_reader()
    config_reader.read()
    url = config_reader.get_value('remote "origin"', 'url')
    return 'pwd' if url.startswith('http') else 'ssh'
```

Comment: `'ssh' if '@' in url` is a wrong test because an http(s) URL may contain `@`: `https://user@git.host/path`. HTTP(S) URLs start with `http`, so your check should be `'pwd' if url.startswith('http') else 'ssh'`.

Comment: Note, however, that this will falsely indicate that `httplogin@example.com:path/to/repo.git` is being accessed via http, when it's actually ssh with user `httplogin`. That's not fatal since the user could write `ssh://httplogin@example.com/path/to/repo.git` instead, as his URL.